# Change template in code (not in template manager)

Tags: joomla

For example having a specific "my_template_1" chosen as default template in the template manager.

How can I switch to another template inside php code, and not touching the template manager?

What php should I edit?

EDIT:
My aim is to have some buttons with template names, user chooses one, the template name is saved in user's parameters and the chosen template is set per user.

Comment: Switch to a different default or switch away from the default in some situation?

Comment: Elin@: switch away from the default

Comment: Do you have code that recognizes the situations where you would switch?

Comment: Elin@: yep, I will switch when user will press a button (that will save template choise in user's paramsi n Joomla)

Comment: If you don't get the right answer here you may want to try the new Joomla Q&A site. http://joomla.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

If you look in `JApplicationAdministrator`  (/libraries/cms/application/administrator.php) at about line 174 you'll see `getTemplate()`  which overrides the basic getTemplate() by allowing choice of template in the user params.  You can use that code as a base for doing the same thing in the front end by writing a system plugin. You want the plugin to run early on in the stack but after the default template for a page is set.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point you may want to look at the source for [this free plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/templating/25304) on the [Joomla Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/).

There is also a paid extension on the JED called [DynamicTemplateSwitcher](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/mobile/mobile-display/21785) which already appears to do what you're trying to implement.